# Git domain alias

Tags: git

Can I redirect a ssh/git URL to another URL? For example:

```
git@gitlab.domain.net:company/project.git
```

would be redirected to

```
git@bitbucket.org:othercompany/project.git
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the desired remotes you need

```
git add remote **remote1** git@gitlab.domain.net:company/project.git
git add remote **remote2** git@bitbucket.org:othercompany/project.git
```

Now you can work side by side with those 2 remotes.

```
gii pull remote1 brancha

git push remote2 brancha
```

This is exactly what remote are for.
Read more about remotes [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes)

Once you set up your remotes you can use them side by side to do your work.

Answer (score 0):

The clean way is clearly to set your remotes properly. But if you really want to alias one host with another, you can do so in `.ssh/config` (read `man ssh_config`) like

```
Host gitlab.com
HostName bitbucket.com
```

This will apply to all your uses of SSH. I'd advice against it since one day you will eventually forget about this alias and complain that `ssh gitlab.com` does not connect to `gitlab.com`.

I don't think you can alias a *path* to another though.